# How can I call a function inside of stateless functional component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my problem I want to call function refresh from MyTable.js into MyPage.js

MyTable.js

```
const MyTable = (props) => {

 //Some state

 const refresh = () => {//Do Refresh}
 
 return(<Table/>);
}

export default MyTable;
```

MyPage.js

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
 //Some state

 const handleRefresh = () => {
  //How to call refresh of MyTable here?
 }

 return(
  <Button onClick={handleRefresh} >Refresh</Button>
  <MyTable />
 )
}
```

//I Want a solution something like this but I don't know how to achieve

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
 //Some state
const [myTable] = MyTable.useMyTable();

 const handleRefresh = () => {
  myTable.refresh();
 }

 return(
  <Button onClick={handleRefresh} >Refresh</Button>
  <MyTable table={myTable} />
 )
}
```

Comment: Whats the error your getting

Comment: There is no error, I don't know how to call the function refresh from different component

Comment: you can't. The only way is to expose a property by MyTable, which MyPage will change.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what your use case is? For what you are telling, you might want to add a button (or any other interactive element) that when pressed will call the refresh function.

Comment: Define the table state and methods in the page component and pass it to table as props? https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: What you want to achieve from refresh. Better have some flag that you pass. and based on that you call your method in child.

Comment: Can I use context for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it but not highly recommended.

You can do it like the following

MyTable.js

```
const MyTable = (props) => {

 props.refresh(() => {
    // DO Refresh
 });

 return(<Table/>);
}

export default MyTable;
```

MyPage.js

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
 //Some state

 let refreshFunc = () => {};

 const handleRefresh = () => {
  //How to call refresh of MyTable here?
  refreshFunc();
 }

 return(
  <Button onClick={handleRefresh} >Refresh</Button>
  <MyTable refresh={r => { refreshFunc = r; }} />
 )
}
```

Comment: absolutely not! that's a function, not an instance of class! what happens when you call it a second time?

Comment: Please elaborate what you say more @MarioVernari
It works fine second time too because the function is set already

Comment: when you call the MyTable function the first time, the `refresh` reference is passed to the parent function. Once the MyTable function exits, the collected reference prevents the GC to trash what's in the function itself, then keeps alive. Now suppose `MyTable` renders itself (e.g. own state change): the assignment will be updated, but in the parent context the `refreshFunc` still references the old handler. At this point, if the parent tries to refresh its child, it won't work.

Comment: @MarioVernari
When assignment is updated, it calls parent prop function props.refresh.
So it is expected that parent context will refer new handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to patch as follows:

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
 //Some state
 const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);

 const handleRefresh = () => {
  setRefresh(x => x + 1);
 }

 return(
  <Button onClick={handleRefresh} >Refresh</Button>
  <MyTable dummy={refresh} />
 )
}
```